# How can I change the value of struct within FUNC?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameters, func

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int i=0,menu;

typedef struct _Person
{
    char name[10] ;
    int tele;
}Person;

void add(Person *pp[i])                   // I want to edit the struct's name 
{
    char aa[10];
    printf("Enter name : ");              
    scanf("%s",pp[i]->name);              //struct pointer's name dynamic memory gets string
}    

int main()
{
    Person *pp[3];

    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        pp[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct _Person));        //
    }
        printf("Select menu \n1.add tele 0. exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);

    while( menu != 0)
    {

        switch( menu )
        {
            case 1: add(?????????); i++; break;       // call add FUNC

        }
        printf("Select menu \n1.add tele\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        printf("%s %s %s", pp[j]->name);             // Then I wanna show the stings in here...

}
```

I want to make kind of telebook !
so tried to make struct style memory in struct pointer
but i don't know what should i put the parameter in add FUNC and make code add part.... ;;(( please help me..

Comment: don't use leading underscores in your own identifiers, they are reserved for the implementation. `struct` tags and type names are in different namespaces, so it's absolutely fine to write `typedef struct Person {...} Person;`.

Comment: why do you dynamically allocate `struct`s if you always have exactly 3 of them? why not just write `Person pp[3];` and be done?

Comment: and does `void add(Person *pp[i])` even compile? what's `i` here? you want to pass this function a pointer to **one** of your structs, so it should just be `void add(Person *pp)`.

Comment: The overall design of your code is poor, especially having twice `printf("Select menu \n1.add tele\n"); scanf("%d", &menu);` is a bad idea.

Comment: `scanf("%s", ...)` is potential **undefined behavior** and always a bug. What happens if you enter a name longer than 9 characters? -> undefined. Better [don't use `scanf()` at all](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), but if you absolutely must, use a field-width, e.g `scanf("%9s", ...)`

Comment: Btw, is `Person.tele` meant to contain a *phone number*? Then, `int` is a **very poor choice**, phone numbers have formatting and may include signs like `+`, `-`, `(`, `)`, `#`, `*` ....

Comment: Please explain what `add` is supposed to do _exactly_.

Comment: for inspiration: https://ideone.com/hcHZ0q

Comment: Um  the add FUNC is for saving name datum,  thank you for all your comments

Comment: @JaeJu assuming your code would work, your `add` function still mixes two aspects: Getting input **and** storing a value in your data structure. In a well-structured program, they shouldn't be mixed. Think about what you'd do if you later want to read your data from a file or database instead of having direct input. A function like your `add` couldn't be reused in that scenario. In my example above, I left all the input out and just wrote the generic functions for a dynamic data structure.

Comment: @Felix Palmen thank you for further advice. I am looking into the link u gave me and I understand what u tried to explain now im going over pointer and dynamic arr parts. can i do quick question? is it impossible to get each dynamic memory space pointed and use the space anywhere i wanna use?  
+ I got the tele number part used as string to use the letters which are not actually nums

Comment: "*is it impossible to get each dynamic memory space pointed and use the space anywhere i wanna use?*" <- sorry, I don't understand this question ....

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the current entry to your add-function

```
void add(Person* current)                   // I want to edit the struct's name 
    {
        printf("Enter name : ");              
        scanf("%9s",current->name);   
    }
```

and

```
add(pp[i]);
```